# Copy a file from windows to another windows using Python

Tags: windows, networking, copy, remote-access, paramiko

I have two windows system: `WIN1` and `WIN2`
I have both systems credentials
I need to copy a file `file.zip` from `WIN1` to `WIN2`

**Requirement:** I don't want to add any services in `WIN2`

I tried `paramiko` but it requires `WIN2` to have `ssh` installed.

Is there any way in `python` from which I can copy a file from `WIN1` to `WIN2`?

Please help
Thanks in advance